# How can I easily script all objects in my databases to search for a certain column and datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Summary:**
I need to script out all of my database stored procedures, functions and views to find all instances of "customer_code char(3)". Is there an easy way to script out all objects? I have 7 database servers, each with 20-30 databases. I don't want to have to open each database and manually generate scripts for each database, it will take too long.

**Background:**
We have a classic problem to solve, similar to W2K. We have a code column that is, char(3) in the database. This is populated with randomly generated letters and numbers to create a unique code that we use to identify customer work. It's 25 years old and we estimate that we have about 4-5 months before we run completely out of combinations. We need to expand this column to a varchar(10) type.

**Bonus:**
I'd ideally like a solution that would also allow me to search through each database's objects, finding and counting instances of "customer_code char(3)".

Comment: What does "objects" mean? You can easily find columns that have a certain name and data type by querying [`sys.columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx), but that won't help you find variable declarations in stored procedures, for example. And scripting objects from SQL Server has been asked [many times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+script+all+objects) before.

Comment: Stored Procedures, Views, and Functions.

Comment: I clicked through the search, but all of the answers say "Click on database, right click, generate script". I'm looking for a more automatic solution.

Comment: The very first question in the search results mentions using [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) to [script database objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx). Did you look into this?

Comment: And since you're interested in searching the text of stored procedures (and other object), [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+search+stored+procedure+text) would be relevant too.

Comment: I'm familiar with SMO, but didn't want to write something from scratch. The text of stored procedures link is interesting though. I have some leads to follow up there. Thanks for those!!

Answer (score 0):

I have developed 2 applications that might help you:

[SMOscript](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/smoscript-0-19/) scripts out all all objects in a given database. It also features a search function that searches all T-SQL modules for a string.

Sometimes when implementing changes, my approach is to intentionally change or delete the item that is to be changed, and have the compiler detect the dependencies. In your scenario, I'd rename the `customer_code` column and check all objects for dependency on that column by invoking each.

The application [checktsql](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/checking-ms-sql-server-objects/) does just that: it loops through view, SPs, etc., executes each of them, and logs the errors. You'll also find a pure T-SQL solution on my blog.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does your SMOscript application take account of different spacing between the column and the size? e.g. customer_code char(3), customer_code    char(3), etc? (I can't seem to get the comment to format properly, but some of my column definitions have one space, some several, some have tabs, some have a combination of tabs and spaces.

Comment: I guess you either have to search for customer_code or for char(3).

Answer (score 0):

RedGate do a piece of free software that plugs into management studio called SQL Search, it indexes all objects in your database and really quickly finds references to objects.

I find it a really handy tool for stuff like this:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Answer (score 0):

To search for specific text in Procedures, Views, and Functions you can just search through syscomments.  This simple query will only search through one database but you could modify to make it loop through all databases on the server.

```
DECLARE @sSearchString VARCHAR(30)

SELECT  @sSearchString = 'YMDEFF'

SELECT Distinct
    ss.name,
    so.Name,
    SO.Type
FROM sys.objects SO (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN syscomments SC (NOLOCK) 
    on SO.object_id = SC.ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss
    ON so.schema_id = ss.schema_id
WHERE SC.Text LIKE ('%'+@sSearchString+'%')
ORDER BY SO.Name
```